# Which version of jdbc4 postgres driver should you include in your product?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I am wondering if there are any reasons why someone would want to include an older version of the postgres JDBC4 postgresql driver.

http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html is listing release versions for 9.0, 9.1 and 9.2 and I do know that even if you put driver 9.2 it will keep working with postgres 9.0 and so one.

Considering that you are not trying to force the clients on using a specific version of Postgres, which version of the driver should you use? … assume that you are going to include a single one.

Comment: What is an 'apostates driver'?

Answer (score 2):

You almost always want to use the current version, as the current version maintains compatibility to (at time of writing) Pg 7.4 servers, but *older versions are not necessarily compatible with newer servers*. So you can use PgJDBC 9.2 with PostgreSQL 8.3, but you can't reliably PgJDBC 8.3 with PostgreSQL 9.2 - you'll have problems with metadata queries, `bytea`, string literal escapes, etc.

Older versions are mostly there for people who're working on isolating bugs/faults/performance issues, and because of very conservative software release and update policies at many organisations. Personally I think they should be on a second "Other versions..." page.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this question is really answerable, it depends on a number of factors, including but not limited to:

- How formal is your testing and release procedure?
- Do you depend on specific behavior of the driver version?

For example if you have a very thorough or formal testing process, you would normally release with the version you tested against. A newer version of the driver might require a very intensive re-testing that is not worth the effort right now (or you simply want to get the product out of the door).

And if you depend on behavior of the driver that was changed (or fixed) in a newer version, that might be a good reason to release with an older version until you have fixed your dependence on the old behavior.

Other than that, I'd suggest to usually release with the latest version, and not keep hanging on to an older version if you don't have a good reason.